# Opening programs on Raspberry Pi from terminal

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi

When I first set up my Rasbperry Pi, I had it running with its own keyboard, mouse and monitor, and I could easily open applications using the terminal (e.g. python idle, etc.).

A few weeks ago I tried setting up X11 Forwarding to my windows machine using Xming and it worked great. But yesterday I tried opening Python IDLE and got the following message:

```
$ idle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1545, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1813, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0"
```

I tried going back to using the Pi directly (mouse, keyboard and monitor attached) and got the same message. Even more mysteriously, my friend's account on the same Pi works fine.

The only remedy I can find is that manually setting the DISPLAY variable solves this completely (when working locally):

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
```

But I don't have time to make this change every time. Is there something I can change in the configuration files to do this? And how can I fix my X11 Forwarding? Any help is appreciated.

**Please note: IDLE is just an example, this is true for any programs with GUIs including the epiphany browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could append that command to `/etc/rc.local` to have it run every time you boot the machine.

Comment: This fixed the problem when working locally but doesn't fix for when I use X11 forwarding. Thanks though!